# What are public app and express.Application

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was learning TypeScript with Node and in that, someone wrote a line that looks like this

```
  public app: express.Application;
```

In the following context

```
import express, { Request, Response }  from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

class App {

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.routes();
  }

  //TODO: What is public app: express.Application
  public app: express.Application;

  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }

  private routes(): void {
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Hello World!'
      })
    });
    router.post('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const data = req.body;
      // query a database and save data
      res.status(200).send(data);
    });
    this.app.use('/', router)
  }
}

const app = new App().app;
const port = 4040;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

I am unable to comprehend what they are doing here and why. Can someone help me in comprehending it?

Comment: I'd recommend reading a basic TypeScript tutorial; that's a typed property declaration. Start with e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html; your specific question will be answered in the classes section.

Comment: An analogous line would be: `public someWord : String = "example";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `public` is not a typescript keyword but js class syntax.

Typescript syntax starts with the `:` after which follows a type - which can be one of several: typescript interface, typescript data type, object; in this case in attribute called `Application` in import called `express`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, 
Can you please also explain why the routes are in private whereas the configuration is in public?

Comment: You access app here: `const app = new App().app;` hence it must be public. `routes` you do not access externally, so it's a good practice to make them private.

Comment: btw, all class properties are public by default - writing out the public keyword is just being explicit but is in no way required.